# Tailwind classes are not generated or not added to css file

Tags: css, webpack, sass, electron, tailwind-css

I have a react project, that is configured using webpack (no vite or create-react-app), uses scss for styling and electron.

I tried to integrate tailwind to it using official guides.

Created tailwind.config.js and postcss.config.cjs. In my main scss file I added the following:

```
@import 'tailwindcss/base';
@import 'tailwindcss/components';
@import 'tailwindcss/utilities';
```

However, when I start the application, it doesn't apply styles from classes. And when I run build, in my output css file I see that the subsequent sccs stiles are being normalized, but code related to tailwind being added like so - @tailwind base;@tailwind components;@tailwind utilities; I suppose this means that tailwind wasn't actually processed?

- I'm correct in assuming that importing tailwind should result in
  actual tailwind styles in output css?
- If so, what can be possible reasons that this is not happening?
- What could be other reasons that tailwind styles are not applied?
- Where could be potential problem in webpack, electron or scss?

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71039049/use-tailwind-with-webpack-5?

Comment: @evolutionxbox, I have webpack 4 and use "@import" already. But for the record, "@tailwind" also doesn't work. I mean, I get the same result with both options